# Complex analytic function equivalent definitions

Tags: complex-analysis

A function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is analytic at $x_0$ iff it is differentiable at $x_0$.

A real function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is analytic at $x_0$ iff it admits a convergent power series in a neighbourhood of $x_0$. Can we extend this to $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$?

In other words, is it true that a function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is analytic iff it admits a convergent power series in a neighbourhood of $x_0$?

Comment: I believe this is correct. The first definition is also called holomorphicity but theorems in complex analysis show that the two are equivalent. (although at the moment the exact logic escapes me)

Comment: Usually analyticity at one point is understood as differentiability in some neighborhood of the point  (not just at the point). With that modification, you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic at $x_0$ if it can be represented by a convergent power series in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

A function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable at $x_0$ if the usual limit definition holds there.

It is a theorem that if $f$ is complex differentiable *in a neighborhood of* $x_0$ then it is analytic at $x_0$, so frequently the terminology gets used interchangeably. However, it is not enough to know it is differentiable at a single point.

$f(z)=\vert z\vert^2$ is differentiable at $z=0$ but not in a neighborhood and not analytic.